# Error While Importing statsmodels.api "AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute '_lib'"

Tags: python, statsmodels

when I `import statsmodels.api as sm` it gives the error `import statsmodels.api as sm`
But if I only `import statsmodels as sm` then it does not give any error

but a few days ago `import statsmodels.api as sm` was also working
and I also tried `pip install statsmodels --force-reinstall --user` But it did not fix the problem

And also my python file is **not** named `statsmodels.py` or `statsmodels.ipynb`

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after I reloaded vs code after running `pip install statsmodels --force-reinstall --user` it fixed my problem